# Is there a formula where I can update cell based on date and text in two cells

Tags: excel

**Objective**
Update Audit Status based Last Recertication Date, Review Cycle and Due Date. So that I can mark the Audit Status Column, Due, Complete or Late.

**Key Data:**

COLUMN E = Last Recertification Date

COLUMN K = Audit Status

COLUMN E = How Long is Certification Valid/Review Cycle (I.e. Monthly and Annual, Every 3 years)

COLUMN M = Due Date (This date already calculated based of column E)

**Current Logic**
IF Last Recertification is in the past: Audit is complete/passed/due
If the certification is in the future: Audit is not complete/not passed/ due

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymzXS.jpg)

Comment: IF() with NOW() should work. I will let you attempt it.

Comment: @TehjpalSingh - Please try to provide sample data and expected output. You can do that using some dummy values. Without that it is very difficult for people to answer. check this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

So, here is something thrown together, making some assumptions:

[image]

Do check the fine detail and check the vlookup table to see if it matches your needs.

Note, al the dates are formatted as dates.

Comment: Thanks this works! - Just need  further clarification on why do we need to perform a vlookup? and I also use IFS statement as well?

Comment: Please see link image attached above. also I'm trying to add logic so that if flags due in 30 days or 6months left if before the deadline on the new recert date

Comment: You don’t have to use vlookup, but I find that it is easier to update a table than edit a long if(). You can choose.