# How to add days based on another date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to add +2 days to column based on other column i use this table :

```
Company   Type Joinning Date  Starting day
1         1    19/01/2019     
2         0    19/01/2019       
3         0    19/01/2019       
4         1    20/01/2019     
5         0    20/01/2019
6         1    21/01/2019
```

i want to add +2 DAYS in column `Starting day` which is `Joining day` + 2 days if the company have type `1` how can i do it ?

```
What i've tried ?
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVZ39.png)

**Desired Results**

```
Company   Type Joinning Date  Starting day
1         1    19/01/2019     21/01/2019
2         0    19/01/2019       
3         0    19/01/2019       
4         1    20/01/2019     22/01/2019
5         0    20/01/2019
6         1    21/01/2019     23/01/2019
```

Comment: `=IF(B2=1,C2+2,"")`

Comment: hello this gives an integer result not a date

Comment: Format as date,

Comment: its already date format

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099392/4961700 give it a vote if it helps.

Comment: @Hercules that formula, given by Scott sir, has no issues, you just need to format as date. Its basic of excel! You should know that in Excel Date & Times are stored as numbers hence when you are adding 2 with a date it gives a number formatting to short date will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show my comment of:

```
=IF(B2=1,C2+2,"")
```

Works.  The output cell must be formatted in the desired method:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works , the output column was date format but somehow the cell i was using is a standard , thanks again